# XSL like or fuzzy search?

Tags: xslt, foreach

Is there any XSL equivalent of the **SQL like** or a **fuzzy search**?

For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="foo[foo_type like '%1%']">
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the XPath expression that you need to use and for a number of standard XPath functions on strings that may come handy in similar cases as yours. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly, but you have a lot of string functions, as `contains`, `starts-with`, etc. You can see MS' documentation on these functions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256195.aspx

Your particular select would be something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[contains(name(),'1')]">
```

Comment: All good answers, this is what i ended up using though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Use ( in the `select` attribute) the standard XPath function [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) as in following XPath expression**:

```
foo[contains(foo_type, '1')]
```

**Depending on the concrete case, other standard XPath functions, as listed below, may also be useful**:

- **[`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with)**
- **[`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with)**
- **[`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring)**
- [**`substring-before()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before)
- [**`substring-after()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-after)
- [**`string()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string)
- [**`string-length()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string-length)
- [**`concat()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat)
- **[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate)**
- [**`normalize-space()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space)
- **[`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches)**
- **[`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace)**
- **[`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-tokenize)**

**Do note** that `ends-with()`, `matches()`, `tokenize()` and `replace()` **are available only in XPath 2.0**.

**One can use the following XPath 1.0 expression for the same purpose as the XPath 2.0 function `ends-with()`:**

```
  substring($s, string-length($s) - string-length($target) +1)
=
  $target
```

is equivalent to:

```
ends-with($s, $target)
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, use

```
<xsl:for-each select="foo[matches(foo_type, '1')]">
```

Unlike SQL, which has a rather primitive and unorthodox pattern syntax, XSLT uses regular expressions which are very close to the syntax used in Perl and most other modern regex dialects.